# How does Batman know that Clark is Superman?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Okay, so I may have missed this but I can't think of the scene in *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice* where this happened.  I know when both Clark and Bruce were in Lex's house for an event, Clark could hear Bruce talking with Alfred about sabotaging Lex's computers so that gave away Bruce's identity as the Bat.

But what scene during the movie did Bruce know that Clark was Superman?  I mean honestly the glasses really don't hide the secret for Clark, lol so maybe Bruce saw through that?  I can't remember.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that Batman knows Clark was Superman? I'm just trying to remember what evidence in the movie gives that impression.. I'm blanking.

Comment: @DominicG. I mean honestly I don't... but an explanation is due since Lois came in and saved Clark from Bruce.. and why they ended up in that situation which would lead Bruce to do research and finally figure it out :)

Comment: I don't think Bruce knew that Clark Kent was Superman.  If he knew, I'm sure knowing Bruce he would have looked into "Clark Kent" more and known that Martha was his mother's name and when Superman said that when Bruce had the upper hand, he would have known that quicker, instead of needing Lois to show up.  Also, I just don't think that there is any other evidence that he did know.

Comment: I think Batman is detective after all. At least he can find that himself or with the help of Alfred.

Comment: How does EVERYONE not know? His entire disguise is a pair of glasses.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that Bruce knows that Clark Kent is Superman until after the climactic fight scene. He certainly knows at the end of the film, since he is in Smallville (major spoiler below), but he could have easily figured it out by then given what he had learned, or either Lois Lane or Martha Kent could have just told him.

> Bruce was in Smallville for Clark's funeral.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was that when The Flash told Bruce during his "knightmare" that "you were right all along. It's Lois lane" I guess Bruce figured out Clark Kent is with Lois lane and put 2 and 2 together

Comment: Then why he got shocked by knowing his mother's name?